# Issues with Wall Script

Tags: php, mysql

There is an issue with my wall script, a single post is shown multiple times on user's own wall and one time on his friend wall. For example if I have 5 friends, the script will show single post 5 times.

As it is showing one time on friend wall, this portion is working good but issue is on user's own wall.

PHP Code:

```
$qfu = "SELECT * FROM my_friends WHERE (user_id = '$user_id' OR friend_id = '$user_id') AND status = '1'";
$fu = mysql_query($qfu) or die(mysql_error());
$rowfu = mysql_num_rows($fu);
while ($rowf = mysql_fetch_array($fu)) {
    $user_id   = $rowf['user_id'];
    $friend_id = $rowf['friend_id'];
    $querymsgs = "SELECT * FROM messages where uid_fk = '$friend_id' OR uid_fk = '$user_id' order by msg_id DESC Limit 1";
    $qmsgs = mysql_query($querymsgs) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_msgs = mysql_num_rows($qmsgs);
    while ($msgs = mysql_fetch_array($qmsgs)) {
        $msg_id     = $msgs['msg_id'];
        $orimessage = $msgs['message'];
        $message    = tolink(htmlentities($msgs['message']));
        $time       = $msgs['created'];
        $privacy    = $msgs['privacy'];
        if ($privacy == '0') {
            $privacy = 'Only Me';
        } elseif ($privacy == '2') {
            $privacy = 'Public';
        } else {
            $privacy = 'Friends';
        }
        $uid           = $msgs['uid_fk'];
        $fullname      = $msgs['fname'] . " " . $msgs['lname'];
        $face          = $Wall->Avatar($uid);
        $commentsarray = $Wall->Comments($msg_id);
?>
```

I have tried the code below too, but it is also showing multiple times same post:

```
$qfu = "SELECT * FROM my_friends WHERE (user_id = '$user_id' OR friend_id = '$user_id') AND status = '1'";
$fu = mysql_query($qfu) or die(mysql_error());
$rowfu = mysql_num_rows($fu);
while ($rowf = mysql_fetch_array($fu)) {
    if ($user_id == $rowf['user_id']) {
        $fid = $rowf['friend_id'];
    } else {
        $fid = $rowf['user_id'];
    }
    $querymsgs = "SELECT * FROM messages M, tbluser U WHERE U.id='$user_id' and M.uid_fk=U.id and (M.privacy='1' or M.privacy='2') order by M.msg_id desc ";
    $qmsgs = mysql_query($querymsgs) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_msgs = mysql_num_rows($qmsgs);
    $msgs = mysql_fetch_array($qmsgs);
    $msg_id = $msgs['msg_id'];
    $orimessage = $msgs['message'];
    $message = tolink(htmlentities($msgs['message']));
    $time = $msgs['created'];
    $privacy = $msgs['privacy'];
    if ($privacy == '0') {
        $privacy = 'Only Me';
    } elseif ($privacy == '2') {
        $privacy = 'Public';
    } else {
        $privacy = 'Friends';
    }
    $uid = $msgs['uid_fk'];
    $fullname = $msgs['fname'] . " " . $msgs['lname'];
    $face = $Wall->Avatar($uid);
    $commentsarray = $Wall->Comments($msg_id);
?>
```

Please help me to get rid off this issue.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: try checking the condition in your sql request there is something fishy about ( user_id = '$user_id' OR friend_id = '$user_id') should'nt you just check for friends belonging to a user? I am guessing that if A is friend with B then B is friend with A and therefor the owner of the post gets caught in your query

Comment: issue is that user's post as shown multiple times. eg if user A have 2 friends then his post will be shown 2 times on his wall, Shimon Rachlenko

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko C'mon Shimon, the problem is crystal clear on the post.

Comment: you are right  legrandviking 51. please make some necessary changes in my script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this statement: `$qfu = "SELECT * FROM my_friends WHERE (user_id = '$user_id' OR friend_id = '$user_id') AND status = '1'";` - if you have 5 friends your id will appear 5 times in result and thus will get this own post 5 times.

You should get rid of the `user_id = '$user_id'` part of the query:
`$qfu = "SELECT * FROM my_friends WHERE friend_id = '$user_id' AND status = '1'";` - this way you get your friends only. You already have your own id, so no need to query for it.

Now you need to put the code for fetching messages into separate function and you are ready:

```
function getMessagesById($authorId) {
    $querymsgs = "SELECT * FROM messages where uid_fk = '$authorId' order by msg_id DESC";
    $qmsgs = mysql_query($querymsgs) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_msgs = mysql_num_rows($qmsgs);
    while ($msgs = mysql_fetch_array($qmsgs)) {
        $msg_id     = $msgs['msg_id'];
        $orimessage = $msgs['message'];
        $message    = tolink(htmlentities($msgs['message']));
        $time       = $msgs['created'];
        $privacy    = $msgs['privacy'];
        if ($privacy == '0') {
            $privacy = 'Only Me';
        } elseif ($privacy == '2') {
            $privacy = 'Public';
        } else {
            $privacy = 'Friends';
        }
        $uid           = $msgs['uid_fk'];
        $fullname      = $msgs['fname'] . " " . $msgs['lname'];
        $face          = $Wall->Avatar($uid);
        $commentsarray = $Wall->Comments($msg_id);
}

//get all own messages
getMessagesById($userId);

//get all friends' messages
$qfu = "SELECT * FROM my_friends WHERE friend_id = '$user_id' AND status = '1'";
$fu = mysql_query($qfu) or die(mysql_error());
$rowfu = mysql_num_rows($fu);
while ($rowf = mysql_fetch_array($fu)) {
    $friend_id = $rowf['friend_id'];
    getMessagesById($friend_id);
}
```